# Close add in task pane from button inside add in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an Outlook add-in and I'd like to close the add-in when I click on the "Close" customized button that I have inside the add-in and not on the "Close" - 'X' button of the add-in.
I was trying to find a reference inside the Outlook add-in documentation but without success.
Which office API request I need to use? any link/reference to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the API to close the add-in is not there. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: I saw from the documentation that we have an option to close the add-in by using the **closeContainer()** function, is that the correct way to get this behavior although there is nothing official from Microsoft?

Comment: You can try that if that works for you, but there is no official Js API for close.